# How to properly load an .XLS file in script

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a python script that opens an `.xls` file to read its lines and store them in a list and then it does a bunch of other things. When I try to call it from Excel like so:

```
Sub SampleCall()
    RunPython ("import sov_reformat;sov_reformat.sov_convert()")
End Sub
```

Here's the first few lines of my script:

```
# In[1]:
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv


# In[2]:
def sov_convert():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    df2 = pd.read_excel("Full SOV.XLS")
    temp_df = df2
```

### I get an error:

### Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "...\sov_reformat.py", line 70, in

```
sov_convert()
```

File "...\sov_reformat.py", line 14, in sov_convert

```
df2 = pd.read_excel("Full SOV.XLS")
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel

```
io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 227, in **init**

```
self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Full SOV.XLS'

I think the line that's causing this error is the following:

```
with open('rates.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rate_combinations = list(reader)
```

But I don't understand why. When I run the script it does exactly what I want so I know everything else is working.

Comment: Read the last line of the error message. Your python script can't find the 'Full SOV.xls' file. Presumably it's not in the same folder as your script, so you'll need to specify the full path (C:\....)

Comment: Thanks! This worked, although I had to search for them like `r'C:\mydir'`